# Is it possible to use SSL without a domain name?

Tags: linux, debian, ssl, openssl

I am using a server with Debian, Apache 2 and OpenSSL installed.

Is it possible to use SSL without a domain name for an internal network?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, try "self-signed" certificates:

http://wiki.debian.org/Self-Signed_Certificate

http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/284

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible to use SSL without a
>   domain name

Yes.